# Python/Kivy : select date from calendar and put into TextInput

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I am using `python-2.7` and kivy. When i click on `cross.png` then calendar open. When i click into calendar then how to get selected date? Actually i need to selected date put into `TextInput`. Can someone tell me that how to make it possible?

## test.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from KivyCalendar import DatePicker
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)

class Calendar(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Calendar, self).__init__()

    def show_calendar(self):
        datePicker = DatePicker()
        datePicker.show_popup(1,.3)


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Calendar()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<Calendar>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 20
        size_hint_y: .5

        Button:
            on_press: root.show_calendar()
            Image:
                y: self.parent.y
                center_x: self.parent.center_x
                allow_stretch: True
                source: 'cross.png'

        TextInput:
            text:""

<DatePicker>:
    pHint: .3, .3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

1. In kv file, add an `id: ti` to TextInput widget.
2. In Python script, create a custom *class of DatePicker* and override `update_value()` method.

Please refer to example for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from KivyCalendar import DatePicker
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)


class CustomDatePicker(DatePicker):

    def update_value(self, inst):
        """ Update textinput value on popup close """

        self.text = "%s.%s.%s" % tuple(self.cal.active_date)
        self.focus = False
        App.get_running_app().root.ids.ti.text = self.text


class Calendar(BoxLayout):

    def show_calendar(self):
        datePicker = CustomDatePicker()
        datePicker.show_popup(1, .3)


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Calendar()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<Calendar>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 20
        size_hint_y: .5

        Button:
            on_press: root.show_calendar()
            Image:
                y: self.parent.y
                center_x: self.parent.center_x
                allow_stretch: True
                source: 'cross.png'

        TextInput:
            id: ti

<DatePicker>:
    pHint: .3, .3
```

## Output

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]

Comment: Unlike your output, the trailing days of month-1 and leading days of month+1 are not inactivated. So, if selected month is january 2019, selecting '31' from dec 2018 returns 31 jan 2019. Selecting '1' from feb 2019 returns 1 jan 2019. Selecting 31 sept 2018 returns nothing. Linux, Python 2.7.13, Kivy 1.10.1, KivyCalendar 0.1.3. Error reading file 'cross.png'. How to inactivate these unhappy days ?