# Can't change an InputBox content in KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to make a InputBox that starts a date picker and when you select a date it will appear in the box. So I tyied like this:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.uix.snackbar import Snackbar
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Predef(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass



class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.birthday = ''
        
        kv = Builder.load_file('file.kv')
        return kv
    

    def on_save(self, instance, value, date_range):
    
        print(value)
        self.birthday = value
        self.root.ids.input_box_date.text = self.birthday


    def on_cancel(self, instance, value):
        print("cancel")
    def date(self):
            date_dialog = MDDatePicker(
                title='Birthday',
                title_input= 'Birthday'
                )
            date_dialog.bind(on_save=self.on_save, on_cancel=self.on_cancel)
            date_dialog.open()
        
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

And this is the code in the kv file:

```
WindowManager:
    MainScreen:
    Predef:
<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width, root.height
        MDToolbar:
            title: "App"
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: side_bar.set_state("open")]]
        Label:
            text: 'Image'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1)

        MDBottomAppBar:
            MDToolbar:
                icon: "botão.png"
                type: "bottom"
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: side_bar
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: '16dp'
            Label:
                color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
                font_size: 35
                text: 'Settings      '
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                pos_hint: {'y': 0, 'left': 1}
            ScrollView:
                MDList:
                    OneLineListItem:
                        text: 'Predefitions'
                        on_release:
                            side_bar.set_state("close")
                            app.root.current = 'Predef'
                            root.manager.transition.direction = "up"
<Predef>:
    name: 'Predef'
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.height, root.width
        MDToolbar:
            title: "Predefinitions"
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: bar.set_state("open")]]
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'top': 1}
        Label:
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
            text: 'Birthday'
        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: input_box_date    
            hint_text: "Birthday"
            text: app.birthday
            size_hint_x : 0.5
            pos_hint: {'center_x' : 0.5}
            on_focus: app.date()
        Label:
            text: ''
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: bar
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: '16dp'
            Label:
                color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
                font_size: 35
                text: 'Settings      '
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                pos_hint: {'y': 0, 'left': 1}
            ScrollView:
                MDList:
                    OneLineListItem:
                        text: 'Main Screen'
                        on_release:
                            bar.set_state("close")
                            app.root.current = 'main'
                            root.manager.transition.direction = "up"
```

When it starts everything is okay. The InputBox starts empty as I expected, but when I click OK button I get this error:

```
'''
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 861, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'input_box_date'
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\program.py", line 112, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 950, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 582, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 347, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 391, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 308, in post_dispatch_input
     wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\behaviors\ripple_behavior.py", line 296, in on_touch_up
     return super().on_touch_up(touch)
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\button.py", line 981, in on_touch_up
     return super().on_touch_up(touch)
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 179, in on_touch_up
     self.dispatch('on_release')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 705, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1248, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1132, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 57, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "<string>", line 213, in <module>
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 705, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1248, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1172, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\program.py", line 77, in on_save
     self.root.ids.input_box_date.text = self.birthday
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
'''
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this error. I tryied replacing the `self.root.ids.input_box_date.text = self.birthday` with `self.root.ids.input_box_date.text = "string"`, but nothing changes. What sould I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says `KeyError: 'input_box_date'`. That means that there is no `input_box_date` key in the `ids` that you used. That key is defined in the `<Predef>:` rule, so that `id` will be in the `ids` of the `Predef` instance. The fix is to access that `id` using the `Predef` instance. Try replacing:

```
self.root.ids.input_box_date.text = self.birthday
```

with:

```
self.root.get_screen('Predef').ids.input_box_date.text = self.birthday
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** A screen is between *root* and *ids* and the date-picker returns `datetime.date` which needs to be converted to *string* for text-field: `self.root.get_screen('Predef').ids.input_box_datex.text = str(value)`.

#### Root and children

In your KV file you have defined two screens inside the *root* `WindowManager`:

```
WindowManager:
    MainScreen:
    Predef:
```

In your python script access this *root* using `self.root`.
So `print(self.root)` will give output similar to:

> <**main**.WindowManager object at 0x7fa580c48f28>

Inside this root, the [`screens`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.screens) can be found as indexed list using `self.root.screens`. A print will output:

> [<Screen name='main'>, <Screen name='Predef'>]

To access a screen by index, e.g. the first use `screens[0]` or for a specific screen by given *id* use [`get_screen(id)`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.get_screen).

As all Kivy widgets the screen has `children`:
All of these child widgets have *ids* that can be listed as dict using `self.root.get_screen('Predef').ids` :

> {'input_box_date': <WeakProxy to <kivymd.uix.textfield.MDTextFieldRound object at 0x7fc1aa8c9c88>>, 'bar': <WeakProxy to <kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer.MDNavigationDrawer object at 0x7fc1a9c9dc88>>}

and accessed by either `ids['input_box_date']` or `ids.input_box_date`.

See also:

- [Multiple Windows With ScreenManager – Python Kivy GUI Tutorial #31 – KivyCoder.com](https://kivycoder.com/multiple-windows-with-screenmanager-python-kivy-gui-tutorial-31/)

#### Set date on text-field

Since the text-field is defined inside screen with id `'Predef'` use either of these:

- `self.root.get_screen('Predef').ids['input_box_date']`
- `self.root.get_screen('Predef').ids.input_box_date`

However the date-picker returns a value of type `datetime` so you need to convert it to string using `str()`:

```py
def on_save(self, instance, value, date_range):
    print("value/type:", value, type(value))
    self.birthday = value  # the instance variable becomes of type date
    self.root.get_screen('Predef').ids.input_box_date.text = str(date)  # convert to string
```

See also:

- [Python/Kivy : select date from calendar and put into TextInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499085/python-kivy-select-date-from-calendar-and-put-into-textinput)

#### Accessing the relevant elements in your tree

```py
print(self.root)
print(self.root.screens)
print(self.root.screens[1].ids)
print(self.root.screens[1].ids.input_box_date)
print(self.root.get_screen('Predef').children)
print(self.root.get_screen('Predef').ids['input_box_date'])
print(self.root.get_screen('Predef').ids.input_box_date)
```

See:

- [Kivy: Get widgets ids and accessing widgets by unique property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35792621/kivy-get-widgets-ids-and-accessing-widgets-by-unique-property)